# Failed to execute goal com.e-gineering:gitflow-helper-maven-plugin:2.2.0:enforce-versions

Tags: maven, git-flow

I have the below error when trying to make a release branch :

The maven project or one of its parents is currently a snapshot version.

Comment: I did figure out that when evaluating the effective POM,  an snapshot version appears